# Form submission canceled because the form is not connected - Console error

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have searched on the net, but still cant find on why my form is not submitting but it shows the data on front end. I'm using hooks to get the data from the form. and is there a way for a better or cleaner line of codes? TIA

This is the console error that I'm getting =>Form submission canceled because the form is not connected

this is my AddUser.js

```
import {Form,FormGroup,Label,Input,Button} from 'reactstrap';
import{GlobalContext} from '../context/GlobalState';
import {Link, useHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';


export const AddUser = () => {

  const {addEmployee } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [nameL,setNameL] = useState('');
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
  const [contact,setContact] = useState('');
  const [address,setAddress] = useState('');
  const [date,setDate] = useState('');

  const history= useHistory();

  const onChange = (e) =>{
      setName(e.target.value);
 
  }
  const onNameL = (e) =>{
 
      setNameL(e.target.value);
     
  }
  const onEmail = (e) =>{
      setEmail(e.target.value);
 
  }
  const onContact = (e) =>{
      setContact(e.target.value);
 
  }
  const onAddress = (e) =>{
      setAddress(e.target.value);
 
  }
  const onDate = (e) =>{
      setDate(e.target.value);
 
  }
  const onSubmit= () =>{
      
      const newEmployee = {
          id: uuid(),
          name,nameL,email,contact,address,date
      }
      
      addEmployee(newEmployee);
      
      history.push('/');

  }

  return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
              <FormGroup >
                  
                  <Label>First Name:</Label>
                  <Input type="text" value= {name}  onChange={onChange} placeholder="enter your First name"></Input>
                  <Label>Last Name:</Label>
                  <Input type="text"value= {nameL}  onChange={onNameL} placeholder="enter your Last name"></Input>
                  <Label>Email:</Label>
                  <Input type="email"value= {email}  onChange={onEmail} placeholder="Email Address"></Input>
                  <Label>Contact Number:</Label>
                  <Input type="number"value= {contact}  onChange={onContact} placeholder="Contact"></Input>
                  <Label>Address:</Label>
                  <Input type="text"value= {address}  onChange={onAddress} placeholder="enter your Address"></Input>
                  <Label>Enter Date of Employment:</Label>
                  <Input type="date"value= {date}  onChange={onDate} placeholder="enter date employed"></Input>
              </FormGroup>
              <Button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</Button>
              <Link to="/" className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
          </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
  )
}
export default AddUser``
```

Comment: What is the code for `GlobalState`?

Comment: ```const addEmployee = (user) =>{
        dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_EMPLOYEE',
            payload:user
        })
    } ```

Comment: while this is from reducer:
```case 'ADD_EMPLOYEE':
            return{
                users: [action.payload, ...state.users]
            }```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just change the button type into button and not submit, and IT WORKS

`<Button type="button" onClick={onSubmit} className="btn btn-success">Submit</Button>`